# jQuery - Magnific popup скрол про открытии

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific

При инициализации модального окна, реализованного с помощью *magnific popup*, происходит скролл наверх страницы, при закрытии возвращение обратно к исходному положению.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как ее можно решить?

Comment: как вариант, сохранять текущую позицию скролла, а после закрытия модального окна, возобновлять сохраненную позицию.

Answer (score 1):

`fixedContentPos: false,` - надо добавить в настройки:

```
$(".popup").magnificPopup({
   type: "inline",
   fixedContentPos: false,
   removalDelay: 300,
   mainClass: 'mfp-width-zoom'
});
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа